# Building a Protein Data Bank (PDB) file

Tags: python, chemistry

I have to model a complex polymer of lysine. It resembles a protein, except the lysines don't always bound with their alpha amine. My goal is to produce a [PDB (Protein Data Bank)](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do) for further calculations.

Do you know any module allowing me to build a molecule? I have special needs, like:

- I have chain of amino acid
- I need to add one more to the chain
- but I have to be able to specify where and how this n+1 amino acid bounds to the previous one
- At the end, I have to be able to generate a PDB file

My first approach was to use the SMILES format, and I can do everything perfectly, except I can not build a pdb at the end, because there is no software capable of handling my number of atoms (> 15000).

Comment: You mean Protein Data Bank when you say PDB?  Because to most Python people, pdb is the Python Debugger.  :)

Comment: Yeah I know :) Yes, I mean Protein Data Bank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution to my problem, even if it's not related to my first question. I followed my first approach to generate my polymer: a python script generating a long SMILE chain. And then, I finally found a software capable of converting such a long chain: Discovery studio visualizer.

I think it works because this software is not based on openbabel. It's not a Python solution, but it does the work.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, I know of two relatively good modules:

### [`pdb-tools`](https://code.google.com/p/pdb-tools/)

> pdbTools is a set of command line python scripts that manipulate wwPDB protein and nucleic acid structure files. There are many programs, both open source and proprietary, that perform similar tasks; however, most of these tools are buried within programs of larger functionality. Thus, relatively simple calculations often involve learning a new program, compiling modules, and installing libraries. To fill a niche (and get the tasks done that I needed done), I started writing my own toolset. This has evolved into the pdbTools suite. The suite of programs is characterized by the following philosophy:
>
> - Each program should run as a stand-alone application with a standard, GNU/POSIX style command line interface.
> - Each program should be written in such a way to allow it to be used as a library of functions for more complex programs.
> - Programs should require a minimum of external dependencies.

### [`biopython`](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page)

> The Biopython Project is an international association of developers of freely available Python tools for computational molecular biology.

Comment: These tools seem great to a lot of things, but do they allow to build non-traditional proteins ? For the little I saw, I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, I've used them to construct PDB files of liquid simulations so they can be fed into pymol for rendering. My "atoms" in this case were not even real atoms, but pseudo-atoms used to represent macro features of the system.

Comment: Ok, I obviously missed the relevant info in the doc so. Wich module did you use ? And you think my stuff is doable with this approach, construct a molecule programmaticaly, by indicating how 2 amino acids bound ?

Answer (score 1):

You could overlay selected atoms from the amino acid and the protein to make an artificial bond in pymol - 
https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Pair_fit

- then export as a .pdb

you can have a play with the molecule/s positions before pairing.